# Capture turbospeed while running a program

Tags: linux, perl, automation

I wanted to create an automation program to capture the turbospeed of the CPU while a program is running.

My automation script should be using perl language.

I did try to use:

```
system("script mytest.txt");
system("./turbostat");
```

When I execute this program, only script line works but not turbostat.

Can someone suggest me any ways through which I can capture the turbospeed?

Comment: You might read from `/proc/cpuinfo` if you're on a common Linux system.  For each core, you can read the "model name", which often includes the processor's design speed, and the "cpu MHz" field, which will tell the core's operating speeds.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know the turbospeed when a program is being executed. i have a program called turbostat that will show the speed of the CPU when i run my benchmark. So I would like to write a code that will automatically record the turbospeed when i run my benchmark :D

Comment: Are you asking about Intel Turbo Boost, and how many multiples of 100MHz or 133MHz are currently in effect? If not, perhaps you could explain what you mean by the term "turbospeed" (which seems to not be common).

Comment: Hi DavidO, turbospeed is the speed of the CPU in MHz when i run a program. For example I would like to know what is the CPU speed when I execute a program called ABC.exe. There is a software called turbostat that will show us the speed when we execute it. My problem is that I need to create a perl script that runs and save the CPU speed when at the same time I am running ABC.exe programme :)

Comment: Most modern CPU's have multiple cores, that might be operating at different clock speeds.  Furthermore, you don't (easily) know which core(s) a given process is utilizing.  But I am guessing that you haven't yet examined the "cpu MHz" fields in `/proc/cpuinfo`, because if you had done so already, you would see that they report the current speed of each core.  This speed changes from one instant to the next, so you'll probably have to monitor, then fork off your worker while continuing to monitor/report.

Comment: I think /proc/cpuinfo only displays the real speed of the CPU when it is fully utilise. But my problem is that I need to know the speed when I execute a program because currently I need to open up another terminal to run the turbostat program to monitor the speed because there are times when I run a program, the speed did not reach its max :)

Comment: You want to launch `./turbostat` while the first command is still running? Launch the first command in the [background](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Background-Processes) so it doesn't block.

Comment: thanks for the link RobEarl

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sys::Info::Device::CPU](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys%3a%3aInfo%3a%3aDevice%3a%3aCPU) module.

***SYNOPSIS***

```
   use Sys::Info;
   use Sys::Info::Constants qw( :device_cpu );
   my $info = Sys::Info->new;
   my $cpu  = $info->device( CPU => %options );

   printf "CPU: %s\n", scalar($cpu->identify)  || 'N/A';
   printf "CPU speed is %s MHz\n", $cpu->speed || 'N/A';
   printf "There are %d CPUs\n"  , $cpu->count || 1;
   printf "CPU load: %s\n"       , $cpu->load  || 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I wanted to know the turbospeed when a program is being executed. i have a program called turbostat that will show the speed of the CPU when i run my benchmark. So I would like to write a code that will automatically record the turbospeed when i run my benchmark :D